# SVG assets vs UIBezierPath - SwiftUI

Tags: svg, swiftui, uibezierpath

Is it better to use the SVG assets in my SwiftUI app and call them in the `Image(...)` initialiser,  or convert them to `UIBezierPath`s using websites like https://swiftvg.mike-engel.com/? There's some advantages with just using the SVG assets themselves, like keeping the colour information (some of the icons have very tricky gradients) and the corner radii.

I know there is also a [tool](https://quassummanus.github.io/SVG-to-SwiftUI/) to convert an SVG icon directly to a SwiftUI `Shape`, and it works great for simple icons but then breaks down with more complex icons.

Maybe there's a big performance benefit to using a `UIBezierPath` – or it could already be rendering the SVG asset as a `UIBezierPath` under the hood.

What would you advise?